# Projection parameters for Gauss Kruger 7 zone Serbia

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, serbia

I can not set  parameters for Gauss Kruger 7 zone Serbia

Comment: Please provide more details: Are you looking for the right values, or where to enter them? Do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 2):

I personally had no luck with predefined coordinate reference systems in QGIS or any other CAD/GIS software for the area of Croatia (Gauss Kruger 5 and 6 zone). If the coordinate system for QGIS that Oyvind proposed does not satisfy your needs, you can try this one. You just have to define it in Custom CRS dialog.

+proj=tmerc +pm=greenwich +lat_0=0 +lon_0=21 +k=0.9999 +x_0=7500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=574.027,170.175,401.545,4.88786,-0.66524,-13.24673,0.99999311067 +units=m

Datum transformation parameters were taken from this [site](http://spatial-analyst.net/wiki/index.php?title=MGI_/_Balkans_coordinate_systems).

Answer (score 1):

The coordinate system you are looking for is probably MGI/Balkans Zone 7. In QGis, it is located under "Projected Coordinate Systems" -> "Transverse Mercator" -> "MGI/Balkans zone 7" (EPSG:31277) in the CRS selection dialog.

In case of a layer, right click the layer and "Set layer CRS".

If you want to set the project CRS, there are two options:

1. If you already have a layer with the CRS set, right click the layer and "Set project CRS from layer".
2. If you want to enforce an existing project CRS, go to Settings -> "Project properties", and select the "Coordinate systems" tab. You probably have to enable "on the fly projections".

Comment: This EPSG definition is deprecated. It has wrong paramters. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this 3 parameter CRS definition in proj4 format:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=21 +k=0.9999 +x_0=7500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=690.9,-190.8,487,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

Parameters are taken from **AGROS - Active Geodetic Reference Network of Serbia**. They are semi-official but they work pretty well.

If you have some permanent point with known Gauss-Kruger/WGS84 coordinates you could check it.

Example>
Point 15491 (data source:**Geodetic Network of Serbia** - http://www.geomreze.rgz.gov.rs/

```
X / Lon (φ) - East      Y / Lat (λ) - North
7576801.0423358         4797612.1494160
```

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: The official values for MGI 1901 as used in GDAL 1.10.0 for EPSG:3909 are `+towgs84=682,-203,480,0,0,0,0`