# Changing of unknown CRS of the shapefile in QGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-openlayers-plugin, serbia

I'm trying to convert "unknown" CRS of the shp to the WGS84 UTM zone N34. I've tried to do it with saving of shp in different CRS (Save as) but I did not succeeded. I've checked the situation with open layers and using of on-the-fly transformation and matching is far from perfect (500-600 m difference).

Unknown CRS has been showed in QGIS as USER 100001 with the following parameters:
 * Generated CRS (+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=21 +k=0.9999 +x_0=7500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs)

It should be a Gaus Kruger projection (Bessel 1841) for Serbia. I've tried also with changing of shp and open layer to MGI 1901/Balkans zone 7 and MGI/3-degree Gauss zone 7 but the situation is the same.

Note: Shapefiles should be very precise as they were obtained by the Public Enterprise. Unfortunately, they're not interest in delivery of the shapefile in a different CRS.

I would be very greatful if someone could help me regarding this issue.

Comment: I did not get everything, I understood first the shape file did not come with the *.prj file, then where the "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=21 +k=0.9999 +x_0=7500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs" came from?

Comment: [Projection parameters for Gauss Kruger 7 zone Serbia](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70515/projection-parameters-for-gauss-kruger-7-zone-serbia)

Comment: What happens if you include a +towgs84 parameter? Try using +towgs84=577.889,165.222,391.183,4.9145,-0.94729,-13.05098,7.78664   See [EPSG registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org), transformation 7676.

Comment: I've received *.prj file (together with cpg, dbf, snb, sbx, shx and shp). I've tried it before Kazuhito  @mkennedy nope, it's the same situation. Parameters that I received are correct for sure, I just need to realize how to transform shp to WGS84 UTM zone N34. I'm a noob for GIS so sorry if I'm not perfectly clear. Do you have other suggestions?Thanks guys for your help so far.

Comment: Is the data freely available? If so, link? Otherwise...if you want to send it to me, I'll delete it the minute I'm finished.  My username @ esri .com

Comment: I wonder... you might be seeing this issue due to Open Layers (Web Mercator - based on spherical projection) as the reference to measure your map's accuracy. Web Mercator ignores ellipsoidal form of the Earth. Can you find a reliable reference point (known xy) in your working area? (I mean, your data is correct while Open Layers is not accurate enough to rely on.)